# Android - Track down why app using so much data

Tags: android, performance, https, androidhttpclient

I am currently having an issue with my app using a lot of mobile data and I am not 100% sure why as the typical request is just JSON sent/received data and typically very small (IE sending username/password for login). Some users are reporting up to 5 GB worth of data used per month. The typical request I have seen is around 1 MB and that is only triggered once per day and the highest I have seen is 3 MB (happens once ever to download additional content). I have used the following below before and after all my `AsyncHttpClient` request and haven't found anything that would make it use that much data as most are less than 0.01 MB.

```
long bytes = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(applicationUID) + TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(applicationUID);
```

I have tried using the profiler in android studio as well, but nothing really spikes over 100kb unless it is a direct network call (when it is supposed to). The only library functions that might use data are from Firebase and Google. Is there a better way to track this issue down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing to `volley`, the easiest solution I have found to go with is to use `stetho` to monitor my network request directly from my browser.

Add stetho to your build

```
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-js-rhino:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.github.darshan-kapasi:StethoForVolley:1.2.1' <~ for volley request
```

Change the following volley request from

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
```

to

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, new StethoVolleyHurlStack());
```

Initialize on main activity

```
Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
```

On your development machine, connect your phone then open `chrome://inspect/` and run your app. You should see it show up under devices, click the inspect panel and you can monitor the network request that you selected.

Resource links

[Stetho Github Repo](https://github.com/facebookarchive/stetho)

[Stetho Volley Github Repo](https://github.com/darshan-kapasi/StethoForVolley)

Answer (score 0):

You could try sending your network requests through a localhost server which passes on the data, while inspecting the traffic through it